# Encrypt the database

Tags: mysql, encryption

I have very sensitive data of mine in the database available in the public domain. Though I have secured it to prevent sql injections, I little bit worried about the data. Can I able to encrypt the entire database using any advance encryption algorithms. Is that a correct way of securing the data? Any suggestions?

Database: MySql

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to understand how a database in the public domain (this has some very specific legal meaning) can contain sensitive data.

What you might perhaps do is encrypt some columns of your database, that is have the encryption and decryption happening in your client application, on some columns of each rows.

Comment: Public domain in the sense my website on the world wide web. Will encrypting and decrypting the columns have a huge impact on the performance?

Comment: First, you could use some more secure language to develop your Web application, like OPA (see http://opalang.org/ for more). Then, regarding performance, it really depends.  Some naive "crypting" functions don't offer top protection, but might be good enough. And the sure way to know is to try and benchmark and measure the performance.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Uh, he doesn't say what language he's using. How do you know OPA would be "more secure" than an unknown language?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch. Thanks for the suggestion. I will work on it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, only data encryption is not the answer.

You should know and control "Who can access and accessed data".

Although you encrypt data itself, attacker can get the encrypted data.
To prevent it, you should control the access privilege or authority.
Also, you should know who accessed encrypted data. Because in these days, data can be stolen by not only external users, but also internal users.

You should encrypt data, control privilege and audit who accessed.

In those days, those three(3) technology have been developed in each way.
Most companies have bought each solutions.

But for personal user, it is hard to buy it and build those environment itself.

I would you like to review [MyDiamo](http://www.mydiamo.com) that provides those three(3) functions.